# Для чего нужен вот этот transform?

Tags: html, css

Есть класс-css с такими полями, не могу понять, что здесь делает строчка `transform` что она задает ?

```
position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смещает блок на 50% от ширины и высоты блока по оси x и по оси y , центрирует объект по центру этот код.

Comment: но тут же уже есть top и left  смещение

Comment: @elik , `top` и `left` смещает сам блок на 50%. А `transform: translate` смещает этот блок относительно ширины и высоты этого блока. Скажем у вас div высотой 200px и шириной 200px , написав `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` вы сместите сам блок на 100px влево и на 100px вверх. Ровно на половину от ширины и высоты самого блока. Таким образом блок станет по центру в данном случае.

Comment: благодарю!!!!! очень внятно

Comment: @elik пожалуйста, принимайте ответ раз разобрались :)